# Warning when an explicitly defaulted function declaration is deleted

Tags: c++, c++11, warnings, compiler-warnings, static-analysis

Is there a diagnostic flag or tool that can **warn me if I have an explicitly defaulted function declaration that the compiler deletes**?

If not, then why? Can a defaulted member being deleted be a desired behaviour? When and how often is this the case?

---

**Details**

I am using clang version 5.0.1, but a warning via a recent MSVC or gcc version would also be fine.

A simplified example of what I had:

```
class NotMoveA
{
public:
  explicit NotMoveA(Foo f);
  ~NotMoveA() = default;
  NotMoveA(const NotMoveA &) = delete;
  NotMoveA(NotMoveA &&other) = default;
  NotMoveA &operator=(const NotMoveA &) = delete;
  //will B deleted w/o warning:
  NotMoveA &operator=(NotMoveA &&other) = default; 
  // ...
private:
  const std::string badDataMemberDisallowingMoveAssignment;
  // ...
}
```

and used `NotMoveA` in a `std::vector`. Since `NotMoveA` is not MoveAssignable, I got some errors whose cause took me quite a while to figure out. A warning directly at the cause, i.e. at the deleted `= default` function, would have helped.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Declaring the main constructor `default` is a syntax error you need to correct. Only Default, Copy, and Move constructors may be declared `default`, non-Default Constructors may not.

Comment: I doubt there would be a compiler warning for this. Defaulted member being deleted is quite often desired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks YSC, Xirema and @user2079303 (+3). I have updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is move the definition of the default member out of the class:

```
class NotMoveA
{
public:
  NotMoveA() = default;
  ~NotMoveA() = default;
  NotMoveA(const NotMoveA &) = delete;
  NotMoveA(NotMoveA &&other) = default;
  NotMoveA &operator=(const NotMoveA &) = delete;
  //will B deleted w/o warning:
  NotMoveA &operator=(NotMoveA &&other); 
  // ...
private:
  const std::string badDataMemberDisallowingMoveAssignment;
  // ...
};

NotMoveA & NotMoveA::operator=(NotMoveA &&other) = default;
```

Once you make it an out of line definition then you will get a compiler error as you cannot define the member function via `= default` if it would be deleted:

> error: defaulting this move assignment operator would delete it after
>   its first
>         declaration NotMoveA & NotMoveA::operator=(NotMoveA &&other) = default;